# /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli: broken symbolic link to /usr/bin/docker

Tags: docker, symbolic-link

I recently installed `Docker Desktop` on Manjaro.

Initially installed Docker Desktop didn't start so I followed the instructions from https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/51

Now Docker Desktop starts up and runs but I can't use it in the terminal. I did some debugging and found out that

`/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli: broken symbolic link to /usr/bin/docker`

After I got this error, every time I run `docker` in the terminal

`exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH`

Current PATH :
`/home/oyedejioyewolemaxwell/.local/share/pnpm:/home/oyedejioyewolemaxwell/miniconda3/bin:/home/oyedejioyewolemaxwell/miniconda3/condabin:$PATH`

What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it on my machine (Manjaro Linux 6.1.26-1)

1. [Install Docker](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/docker/) with `sudo pacman -S docker`
2. Then [install Docker-Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/archlinux/#install-docker-desktop)
3. Check your `$PATH` with `echo $PATH | grep com.docker.cli`
4. If the `grep` command in step #3 returns nothing:

   1. Open your shell config. Example, for [zsh](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/zsh) use `vim ~/.zshrc`
   2. And add this line `export $PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli"`
   3. Restart your terminal or with zsh run `exec zsh`
5. Try again.